# javascript can not identify dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have three select tags in my page and their options are created dynamically. When I change the first menu, second menu generates perfectly. If I change the first menu again, second menu changes perfectly. When I change the second menu, third menu generated perfectly. But if I change the second menu again then firebug show an error saying **document.getElementById("third_list") is null**. How to resolve this? And besides why is this happening? I have created the third select tag in my page already. Just generating the options subtags dynamically. So any solutions?

```
<body>
    <select id="first_list">  
    //menus are fetched by external functions
    </select>
    <select id="second_list" hidden="true">
    </select>
    <select id="third_list" hidden="true">
    </select>  

    <script>  

    $("body").on('change', '#first_list', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax - Copy.php',
            type:'POST',
            async:true,
            data:{
                var1: $('#first_list').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                //alert(response);
                var a=(response.toString()).indexOf("<select");
                var b=(response.toString()).indexOf("</select>");
                var c=response.substring(a,b);
                document.getElementById("second_list").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("second_list").outerHTML=c;
            },
            complete:function(){
                //alert("complete");
            }
        });
    });  


    $("body").on('change', '#second_list', function( e ) { 
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'ajax - Copy.php',
            type:'POST',
            async:true,
            data:{
                var1: $('#second_list').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                var a=(response.toString()).indexOf("<select");
                var b=(response.toString()).indexOf("</select>");
                var c=response.substring(a,b);
                document.getElementById("third_list").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("third_list").outerHTML=c;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementById` requires a string _without_ the hash. If you want to use the hash, use `document.querySelector()` - So, `document.getElementById('third_list')` or `document.querySelector('#third_list')` should get you the correct element.

Comment: Well I didnt use any hash in my code. Its just the error firebug shows me. Maybe it was a typing mistake.

Comment: What does your response look like anyhow? Could you give us an example of a response? And why use `outerHTML` and not just `innerHTML` as I am assuming your id might be gone after your replaced the element.

Comment: This is my response after changing the first list. Following lists will generate similar response.


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
        <select id="second_list">  
                <option value="2010000">Dean Office</option>
                <option value="2020000">Registrar Building Office</option>
                <option value="2030000">Other Office</option>
        </select>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Aha maybe this is it I should try innerHTML. Shouldn't have missed it though and thanks anyway.

Comment: I do have to say that maybe it would be easier to _only_ print the _contents_ of the select table as a response (or even better: use JSON and then use the values to populate the already existing boxes).

Comment: Well I am providing the id in my response. So using outerHTML is not the issue. Besides I am using outerHTML because I can use indexOf for <select> tag. But I can can not use indexOf for <option> because there are a lot of it. If I can not separate only the <options> I can not use innerHTML.

Comment: Alright I have found the solution. Although this code isn't working but I found another way to work only with innerHTML and will not try to mess with outerHTML. Thanks a lot guys for your responses.

Comment: I would like to add that my suggestion was to _simply not include the stuff you are discarding anyhow_. JSON would be even better since you are using ajax to fetch more data over the network, which means the less data you need to send the faster and better your performance will be. Good luck, though.